# Pointing to a specific host under a group, Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I have multiple host details under one group in my Ansible hosts file. Like below,

```
[web-server]
10.0.0.1 name=apache ansible_ssh_user=username
10.0.0.2 name=nginx ansible_ssh_user=username
```

My ansible playbook,

```
---
  - hosts: web-server[0]
    roles:
      - role: apache
```

These details gets added dynamically in the hosts file and I have no control over the order of lines getting added under a group. Hence I can't use the logic web-server[0] or web-server[1]

I want to mention the host by filtering based on the "name" parameter in the playbook since name will be unique. Is there a way to do this, Kindly help.

Comment: Can you not create new groups for your apache and nginx servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can modify inventory file generation process, make it like this:

```
[web-server]
apache ansible_host=10.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_user=username
nginx ansible_host=10.0.0.2 ansible_ssh_user=username
```

And then use:

```
- hosts: apache
```

Comment: What if I have multiple groups with same hostname? In that case what would be the approach?

Comment: @shwetha depends on your task. Usually host names are meaningless and group names have functional names, and you call plays with group names. So having one host in different groups is not a problem.